# Последовательный вывод нескольких элементов разных массивов в React

Tags: javascript, массивы, map, reactjs

Необходимо вывести элементы из двух разных массивов. Проект ругается на синтаксическую ошибку в строке выделенной звездочками. В чем ошибка?

```
const React = require('react')
import { Link } from 'react-router'
import { rhythm } from 'utils/typography'

class Post extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const { route } = this.props
    const post = route.page.data
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.route.page.data.title}</h1>
        <p>Here is my previous project with React:</p>


                { this.props.route.page.data.images.map((image) => (
                  <img key={image} src={image} />
                  **{ this.props.route.page.data.items.map((item) => (**
                        <span key={item}>{item}</span> 
                    )) }
                )) }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
Post.propTypes = {
  route: React.PropTypes.object,
}
export default Post

exports.data = {
  title: "Portfolio",
  date: "2017-05-31",
  img: "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/5e/bb/c1/5ebbc19e05fc6ed9a6eae8ab1760df79.jpg",
  path: "/portfolio/",
  numbers: ['1','2','3'],
  items: ['One', 'Two', 'Three'],
  images: ['https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/5e/bb/c1/5ebbc19e05fc6ed9a6eae8ab1760df79.jpg', 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/41/ee/53/41ee53e21e0c8c5d2eb1243277a97842.jpg', 'https://scontent-frx5-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/p110x80/15966148_1343520962385738_1793700048763115117_n.jpg?oh=a88df4eafd01bf77c1042de71435d749&oe=59E104F6']
}
```

Данные хранятся здесь:

```
exports.data = {
  title: "Portfolio",
  date: "2017-05-31",
  img: "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/5e/bb/c1/5ebbc19e05fc6ed9a6eae8ab1760df79.jpg",
  path: "/portfolio/",
  numbers: ['1','2','3'],
  items: ['One', 'Two', 'Three'],
  images: ['https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/5e/bb/c1/5ebbc19e05fc6ed9a6eae8ab1760df79.jpg', 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/41/ee/53/41ee53e21e0c8c5d2eb1243277a97842.jpg', 'https://scontent-frx5-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/p110x80/15966148_1343520962385738_1793700048763115117_n.jpg?oh=a88df4eafd01bf77c1042de71435d749&oe=59E104F6']
}
```

Comment: Весь элемент в реакт должен быть "упакован" в один внешний dom. Возможно, Вы выводите 2 отдельных dom-элемента. Покажите, пожалуйста, код класса (или render-а) полностью.

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n, внесла полностью компоненту в вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Скобку фигурную закрыли не там :)

> ```
>   { this.props.route.page.data.images.map((image) => <img key={image} src={image}/> )}
>   { this.props.route.page.data.items.map((item) => <span key={item}>{item}</span> )}
> ```

Можно вот так попробовать (данные я в state засунул для своего удобства исключительно)

```
render() {

    let images = this.state.images.map((image) => <img key={image} src={image}/> );
    let items = this.state.items.map((item) => <span key={item}>{item} );

    return(
      <div>
        {images.map((image, index) => <div>{image}{items[index]}</div>)}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: В таком случае, у меня выводится рад картинок, а потом ряд span, а мне нужно, что выводилось img и сразу под ним span, и так три раза :(

Comment: @ValeriaShpiner чуть подправил, попробуйте. Вообще неплохо было бы до рендера (в конструкторе, например) нормальным JSом (а не ковыряться в jsx) сформировать массив объектов (img, span) и в нормальном виде выводить всё это дело.